# Ubuntu stopped seeing SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a problem and I hope the Ubuntu community can help me out here. In short: ubuntu lost the partition of my ssd.

How it happened: I was looking through my external hard drive searching for an ebook. Once I found that pdf (around 100mb), I highlighted it and pressed ctrl+c and the system froze. I couldnt kill the process, nothing would unfreeze it, so for the first time in my life I googled how to restart this OS the hard way. I found the SysRq button method, but I mistyped it a bit: REI**USB**.
Maybe this messed up the system, since I then later saw the comments for each letter and well i remounted all the systems and then synced all mounted systems.

Anyways, from that point on, the SSD disappeared from everywhere, even the bios.
That was the only drive I had and Ubuntu was the only OS installed on it. I have loaded the LIVE CD from USB, tried looking up the partitions.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: UFD 2.0 Silicon-Power8G (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 8054MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8054MB  8053MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Gparted shows the same picture. So only the USB with the LIVECD is available. 
And apparently it doesn't allow me to reinstall ubuntu, because there is no partition available for that (besides the usb).

Any ideas what can be done? If the SSD is dead, why did it happen? Where are the guarantees that this will not happen again with a brand new ssd? 
SSD: 128GB Kingston V300.

Alex.

Comment: Can any other computers see the drive?

Comment: Unfortunately, can't test that atm, no 2nd device available besides the telephone. I will grab a sata-usb tomorrow somewhere and test that out.

Comment: SSD's have a lifecycle limited by write cycles. Be that as it may, The warranty is typically about 3 years on them. If further testing determines that the drive is shot, check to see if it's still in warranty. As these are [still available](https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-Digital-SSDNow-SV300S37A-120G/dp/B00A1ZTZOG) depending on when you bought it, it may still be covered by the manufacturer.

Comment: Elder, when I last checked with SSDLife, it showed 97% of health. 2-3 weeks has passed since then. Could it really be the case?

Comment: Thank you every body, Owen and @Elder. 
It turned out that changing to another set of cables helped. But I learned that most probably the death of SSD will be sudden, so backup is crucial. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted!